# ObservableCollection - Cannot update UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've a problem using ObservableCollection, in particular when I add an item to it the UI doesn't update the Grid. Before explain in details, I want show you the xaml structure interested:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Playing}">
    <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Data" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Minuto" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Minutes}"/>
        </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
```

How you can see I've a Grid with two columns with the following bindings: `Date` and `Minute`. In this way I can update a specific item detail.

This Grid is part of my MainWindow.xaml, at the top of all I've set the datacontext like this:

```
 xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:Live.Resources.UI.ViewModels"
```

and:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <VM:LiveViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

in my LiveViewModel I've this class definition:

```
public partial class LiveViewModel : ViewModel
{

    private ObservableCollection<Models.Playing> _playing = new ObservableCollection<Models.Playing>();

    public ObservableCollection<Models.Playing> Playing
    {
        get { return _playing; }
    }
    ...
```

the class extend the base ViewModel that have inside the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, just for completeness:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
     if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
     field = value;
     OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
     return true;
}
```

now my ObservableCollection is based on the Playing Model that have this definition:

```
public class Playing : ViewModel
{
    private string _dateTime;
    private string _minutes;

    public string Date
    {
        get { return _dateTime; }
        set { SetField(ref _dateTime, value); }
    }

    public string Minutes
    {
        get { return _minutes; }
        set { SetField(ref _minutes, value); }
    } 

    ...
```

also this class implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

So when I add an item to my collection I did this (in my MainWindow.xaml):

```
LiveViewModel lsVm = new LiveViewModel();

        var playingCollection = lsVm.Playing;

        playingCollection.Insert(0, new Playing
        {
            Date = "03/07/2016",
            Minutes = "5",
            Home = "foo",
        });
```

unfortunately the in the Grid I cannot see any element added.
This instead doesn't happen if I create a static collection, infact if I set the ObservableCollection as static I can see the element added, but I also have other properties with non static and this aren't updated.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Have you set `ItemSource` binding in your `DataGrid`? Because I don't see any.

Comment: @hazevich yes, sorry I update the question

Comment: Is `lsVm` instance of your ViewModel is the same instance used in your view where the `DataGrid` is?

Comment: @hazevich yes, I've created the instance in the MainWindow.xaml, and sorry for the mistake but is a Grid not a DataGrid

Comment: How do you set `DataContext` of your MainWindow? Is it some ViewModelLocator?

Comment: @hazevich I've set it in the xaml of MainWindow, all your question is in my topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is why you're getting this behavior is because your `lsVm` instance of the `LiveViewModel` is not the same instance in the `DataContext` of the `MainWindow`.

Here what happens - once the window is created it creates an instance of the `LiveViewModel` and sets the `DataContext` as you're provided these lines of code

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <VM:LiveViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

As far as you're modifying the collection from the code-behind of `MainWindow.xaml` there are to ways you can fix this:

1 You need to access the `ViewModel` using `DataContext`, so your could will look like this:

```
var lsVm = this.DataContext as LiveViewModel;

if (lsVm != null)
{
    var playingCollection = lsVm.Playing;
    playingCollection.Insert(0, new Playing
    {
        Date = "03/07/2016",
        Minutes = "5",
        Home = "foo",
    });
}
```

2 Once you created instance of the `LiveViewModel` from the code-behind, you need to set the `DataContext` using this instance:

```
LiveViewModel lsVm = new LiveViewModel();

this.DataContext = lsVm;

var playingCollection = lsVm.Playing;

playingCollection.Insert(0, new Playing
{
    Date = "03/07/2016",
    Minutes = "5",
    Home = "foo",
});
```

**UPD**
Also if you're using the second approach you ofcourse don't need to set the DataContext from the XAML code.